# Using .replace() with a List in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get python to read a txt file and then replace certain words in it to "XXXX"
I have a list that contains all of the words but the problem is **return doesn't accept lists!**
I have tried doing

```
def email2(email):

  proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

  for words in email:

    if "she" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("she", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "personality matrix" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("personality matrix", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "sense of self" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("sense of self", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "self-preservation" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("self-preservation", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "learning algorithm" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("learning algorithm", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "her" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("her", "XXXX")
      return replaced

    if "herself" in email:
      replaced = email.replace("herself", "XXXX")
      return replaced
    

print(email2(email_two))
```

and this works and does what I need it to (with a bit of tinkering) but as you can see, the code is unnecessarily WAY TOO LONG and I was hoping if any of you could teach me a way I could make it more compact if only I could get all the words in the list proprietary terms to be replaced without having to type all the words in a if statement one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t loop over characters in the email (if `email` is of type `str`, then `word` is a character, not a word!) — loop over the proprietary terms.

Your code is also returning prematurely, it will never replace more than one word. And lastly, the `if … in email` check is redundant, leave it out.

```
def email2(email):
  proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

  for word in proprietary_terms:
    email = email.replace(word, "XXXX")

  return email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `proprietary_terms` list and check if the word in the list exists in the `email`, if it does, you can replace it:

```
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

for word in proprietary_terms:
    if word in email:
        email = email.replace(word, "XXXX")
return email
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_email(email):

    proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

    for word in proprietary_terms:
        if word in email:
            email.replace(word, "XXXX")

    return email
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (shorter) way to do it using the `re` package:

```
import re
def check_email(email):
    proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]
    return re.sub('|'.join(proprietary_terms),'XXXX',email)
```